# How do I return a valid response in This Case in Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am new to Flask, I wanted to know few things around it, like how to create a REST api
i am getting this error `TypeError: The view function for 'create_employee' did not return a valid response`

Been checking some stuff on the internet and not been able to see this to solve this correctly.

My source code is looking like this :

```
import pymysql
from app import app
from config import mysql
from flask import jsonify
from flask import flash, request


@app.route('/api/create',methods=['POST'])
def create_employee():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['name']
        _email = _json['email']
        _phone = _json['phone']
        _address = _json['address']
        _salary = _json['salary']

        if _name and _email and _phone  and _address and _salary and request.methods == 'POST' :
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            query = "insert into empData (name, email, phone, address, salary) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
            bindData = (_name, _email, _phone, _address, _salary)
            cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
            conn.commit()
            respone = jsonify({"message":"OK"})
            respone.status_code = 200
            return respone
        else:
            return showMessage()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@app.route('/api/employee')
def listEmployee():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("select * from empData")
        empRows = cursor.fetchall()
        respone = jsonify(empRows)
        respone.status_code = 200
        return respone
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@app.route('/api/employee/<int:emp_id>')
def listsingleEmployee(emp_id):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("select * from empData where id = %s", emp_id)
        empRows = cursor.fetchone()
        respone = jsonify(empRows)
        respone.status_code = 200
        return respone
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@app.route('/api/update',methods=['PUT'])
def update_employee():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['name']
        _email = _json['email']
        _phone = _json['phone']
        _address = _json['address']
        _salary = _json['salary']

        if _name and _email and _phone  and _address and _salary and request.methods == 'PUT' :
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
            #query = "insert into empData (name, email, phone, address, salary) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
            query = "update empData set name = %s, email = %s, phone = %s, address = %s, salary = %s"
            bindData = (_name, _email, _phone, _address, _salary)
            cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
            conn.commit()
            respone = jsonify({"message":"OK"})
            respone.status_code = 200
            return respone
        else:
            return showMessage()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



@app.errorhandler(404)
def showMessage(error=None):
    message = {
        'status': 404,
        'message': 'Record not found: ' + request.url,
    }
    respone = jsonify(message)
    respone.status_code = 404
    return respone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am just starting out with Flask today. I kind of need clarification in this point.

Comment: You should always return in case of app.route you should not just use print statement

Comment: i said, i am new to this, So i am not sure i understand exactly what u mean, i come from a Node.JS angle

Answer (score 0):

In flask,you not need return a response,just need return `jsonify()`,maybe you need read the document carefully

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :) Thanks people. had to closely look at the documentation and some quick videos again

The code looks like this

**main.py**

```
import pymysql
from app import app
from config import mysql
from flask import jsonify
from flask import flash, request


@app.route('/api/create',methods=['POST'])
def create_employee():
    _json = request.json
    _name = _json['name']
    _email = _json['email']
    _phone = _json['phone']
    _address = _json['address']
    _salary = _json['salary']

    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "insert into empData (name, email, phone, address, salary) values (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"
            #query = "update empData set name = %s, email = %s, phone = %s, address = %s, salary = %s"
    bindData = (_name, _email, _phone, _address, _salary)
    cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    output = {'name':_name, 'email':_phone, 'address':_address, 'salary':_salary, 'message':'ok'}

    return jsonify({'result':output})



@app.route('/api/employee')
def listEmployee():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("select * from empData")
    empRows = cursor.fetchall()
    respone = jsonify(empRows)
    respone.status_code = 200
    return respone



@app.route('/api/employee/<int:emp_id>')
def listsingleEmployee(emp_id):
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("select * from empData where id = %s", emp_id)
    empRows = cursor.fetchone()
    respone = jsonify(empRows)
    respone.status_code = 200
    return respone
    


@app.route('/api/update',methods=['PUT'])
def update_employee():
    _json = request.json
    _name = _json['name']
    _email = _json['email']
    _phone = _json['phone']
    _address = _json['address']
    _salary = _json['salary']

    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "update empData set name = %s, email = %s, phone = %s, address = %s, salary = %s"
            #query = "update empData set name = %s, email = %s, phone = %s, address = %s, salary = %s"
    bindData = (_name, _email, _phone, _address, _salary)
    cursor.execute(query,bindData)  
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    output = {'name':_name, 'email':_phone, 'address':_address, 'salary':_salary, 'message':'ok'}

    return jsonify({'result':output})



@app.errorhandler(404)
def showMessage(error=None):
    message = {
        'status': 404,
        'message': 'Record not found: ' + request.url,
    }
    respone = jsonify(message)
    respone.status_code = 404
    return respone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

**config.py**

```
from app import app
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'empdb5'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Which is exactly what i needed, Just need to have good understanding og indentation. Thanks everyone.